# type mismatch error for variable declared

Tags: excel, vba

```
Dim i, Dif, RootPathLen As Integer

i = Destbook.Sheets(Sheet1).Range("DD99").Value

Selectdata = ActiveSheet.Range("DD" & 99 + i).Value
```

Here on 2nd line i am getting a type mismatch error when the range DD99's value is an integer.

Comment: Is the cell formatted as an Integer?

Comment: can we have data to test on our own machine....

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Make it **Long** .........................